# How to receive data from Dialog Fragment in another fragment's setOnMapLongClickListener listener

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

So this is my public View onCreateView method. I want to open dialog window when user long clicks on map, then take data from the dialog and then set .tittle according to data user inputted into the dialog. I tried doing it with interface but it would not have the data when I need it. getInput() is where I want to receive the data from Dialog fragment.

```
            mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    //FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    DialogMap dial = new DialogMap();
                    dial.setTargetFragment(MapFragment.this, 1);
                    dial.show(getFragmentManager(), "Add a catch");

                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng)
                                .title(getinput())
                                .snippet("Your marker snippet")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fish_icon_map)));
```

[image]
[image]

This is my dialog's fragment.

Comment: Please **don't** post your code as images.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed initialization of dialog listener in DialogMap.

public onDialogOk dialog . ( you have to init this before use)

```
dialog = (onDialogOk)getTargetFragment()
```

So inside the onCreateView() , you can init it.

Comment: I have it here   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            dialog = (onDialogOk) getTargetFragment();

        }
        catch (ClassCastException e){}
    }

Comment: public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng)

store this LatLng in a global variable.

Now in a fragment where you have implemented your onDialogOK interface
you have override sendInput(params) method

inside this method
set marker again 
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng)
                                .title(Title from params )
                                .snippet("Your marker snippet")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fish_icon_map)));